# Check if particular string exist in text either at first or second position

Tags: python, string

I am trying to find the list of strings in the entire column of data frame “Name”. If particular string is exist at first or 2nd position then it should replace the text value of column with that particular string and store it in another column.

For that I am using regex. Below is my code. However, in the output table I am getting match against the “MEDICO SYSTEMS FUJI” as “FUJI” But my requirement is as it exist at 3rd position it should return “NA”.  Similarly for text “SAFEAIR TERM LTD CONTRACTORS” getting match as “LTD CONTRACTORS”. It should show NA as the position is 3rd.

please check my current output table from the existing script and my desired output table.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['KK FUJI PARLIGHT','NORTHWINDS ABATEMENT LLC',
'SAFEAIR TERM LTD CONTRACTORS','MEDICO SYSTEMS FUJI','TOKAI','FUJI CONTRACTOR']})

strings = ['FUJI','NORTHWINDS ABATEMENT','LTD CONTRACTORS']
pattern = '|'.join(strings)

def pattern_searcher(search_str:str, search_list:str):

    search_obj = re.search(re.compile(r'\b({0})\b'.format(search_list),flags=re.IGNORECASE), search_str)
    if search_obj :
        return_str = search_str[search_obj.start(): search_obj.end()]
    else:
        return_str = 'NA'
    return return_str

df['matched_str'] = df['Name'].apply(lambda x: pattern_searcher(search_str=x, search_list=pattern))
```

Current output:

```
Name                                 matched_str
KK FUJI PARLIGHT                     FUJI           
NORTHWINDS ABATEMENT LLC             NORTHWINDS ABATEMENT
SAFEAIR TERM LTD CONTRACTORS         LTD CONTRACTORS
MEDICO SYSTEMS FUJI                  FUJI
TOKAI                                NA
FUJI CONTRACTOR                      FUJI
```

Desired output:

```
Name                             matched_str
KK FUJI PARLIGHT                 FUJI
NORTHWINDS ABATEMENT LLC         NORTHWINDS ABATEMENT
SAFEAIR TERM LTD CONTRACTORS     NA
MEDICO SYSTEMS FUJI              NA
TOKAI                            NA
FUJI CONTRACTOR                  FUJI
```

Comment: If by position you mean words (separated with spaces) I don't think you need regex... Just use [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split): `word in sentence.split()[:2]`

Comment: Why does the third example should match? it doesn't match with the first 2 words...

Answer (score 0):

```
def trim_replace(sequence, target, replacement, n=2):
    return [val if val != target else replacement for val in sequence.split()[:n]]


target_value = "TOP"
sequence = "BEA TOP LIST"
result = replace_in_first(sequence, target_value, "REPLACED")

print(result)
```

Output:

```
['BEA', 'REPLACED']
```

Comment: Yes, I missed to mention one thing, my requirement is also to replace the text with the found text..Thats why, I used regex. In this case, if "LIST" exist at first or second position then replace the text with LIST otherwise retain the same text.

Comment: @GeetanjaliKumar I don't understand your desired output. If it is found you already know what it is (`LIST` in this case). What's wrong with the original answer?

Comment: I have just added the picture of my desired output.Please have a look.

Comment: Still, I don't understand what was the problem with the original answer. There is nothing special there, if `LIST` was in the string you write `LIST` to the new column. So, you just need to know if `LIST` was there, no need for regex or elaborate logic... @GeetanjaliKumar

Comment: There might few cases where I will have more than one word as a string to be find. For example:  string "BEA TOP" to search in text "BEA TOP LIST". It should show as a match exist. If I use str.split it will split the words. Adding one more table of desired output.

Comment: You will have to make your question more clear with a few examples. Don't put pictures of tables. Show a few inputs with your expected output @GeetanjaliKumar

Comment: @OrY anyway this can be adjusted to his new requirements by doing `target in " ".join(sequence.split()[:2])`

Comment: @Tomerikoo that was basically my original answer, I am now confused from his requirements, I'll edit it to what I understand now

Comment: Sorry, If i am making you confuse. I am new to Stackoverflow. Figuring out to put my question in proper format

Comment: @GeetanjaliKumar No worries and welcome! Check my latest update, see if it works for you

Comment: unfortunately, my requirement is different. I have rephrase my question and added more examples. Please check.